# Jenkins post build step as a Function

Tags: function, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins, I know I can do this...

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Demo') {
            steps {
                MyFunction()
            }
        }
    }
}

void MyFunction() {
    sh 'ls /'
}
```

In this situation, the function is within the pipeline, but then I can always extract `MyFunction` into a shared library for reuse across pipelines.

But would it be possible to do this with a post-build step?

In this case, I would like to convert this into a function and extract it into a library.

```
    post {
        always {
            /* clean up our workspace */
            deleteDir()
            /* clean up tmp directory */
            dir("${workspace}@tmp") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            /* clean up script directory */
            dir("${workspace}@script") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            dir("${workspace}@2") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            dir("${workspace}@2@tmp") {
                deleteDir()
            }            
        }
    }
```

I've tried this

```
    post {
        always{
            test()
        }
    }
}
```

With Function

```
void test() {
         {
            /* clean up our workspace */
            deleteDir()
            /* clean up tmp directory */
            dir("${workspace}@tmp") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            /* clean up script directory */
            dir("${workspace}@script") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            dir("${workspace}@2") {
                deleteDir()
            }
            dir("${workspace}@2@tmp") {
                deleteDir()
            }            
        }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Is this possible at all or am I just missing something really obvious?

Comment: Pass variables such as  ${workspace}@tmp  as parameters to your function. Such vars are populated by Jenkins and would not be in scope as you have written this above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the name of the workspace as a parameter in the function will solve your issue. The below script works.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        always{
            echo "In : ${env.WORKSPACE}"
            test(env.WORKSPACE)
        }
    }
}

void test(workspace){
    echo "In test : " + workspace
    deleteDir()
    dir("${workspace}@tmp") {
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

Also, instead of calling `deleteDir()` for multiple tmp directories, if you call `deleteDir()` only once, then it will delete the workspace as well as tmp directories

Comment: You're absolutely right. The only reason I'm having to call `deleteDir()` several times is because there are a number of other directories being created. `demo@tmp`, `demo@2`, `demo@script`

Comment: Agreed. Try passing workspace name as parameter to the function as shown in the solution.

Comment: I might be doing the wrong thing, maybe that's its not working. Are you able to update the answer please?

Comment: Hey @Hammed what do you mean by update the answer? Can you try the above answer? It worked for me.

Comment: I must have missed something. Thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The way that works for us to clean up the workspace after a specific stage and without trying to guess the folder name is to make your post function in stage:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
            post {
                cleanup {
                    script {
                        // Workspace Cleanup plugin
                        cleanWs deleteDirs: true, 
                            notFailBuild: true, 
                            cleanWhenAborted: true, 
                            cleanWhenFailure: true, 
                            cleanWhenSuccess: true

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We use [WorkspaceCleanup plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/).

Comment: Does this clean up tmp directories as well? For some reason, it doesn't for me and I'm always left with `demo@tmp, demo@2, demo@script and demo@2@tmp` directories left uncleaned.

Comment: `@script` folders are usually created on master node. We have a periodic job that erases  those folders if they haven't been modified in the last couple of hours.